# What is the differential $dN_p$ of the Gauss map $N$ of a regular orientable surface $S$ and why is it a linear map on $T_p(S)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry, definition

The Gauss map $N:S\rightarrow S^2$ takes a point of the regular orientable surface $S$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$) and outputs a point in the unit sphere $S^2$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$). After having defined such a map, do Carmo writes

"It is straightforward to verify that $N$ is differentiable. The differential $dN_p$ of $N$ at $p\in S$ is a linear map from $T_p(S)$ to $T_{N(p)}(S)$. Since $T_p(S)$ and $T_{N(p)}(S)$ are the same vector spaces, $dN_p$ can be understood as a linear map on $T_p(S)$."

---

1. What is meant with "differential" here? Because of the notation I thought do Carmo was referring to the total derivative, yet this does not seem to be the case since the total derivative of $N$ would be a function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.
2. Why is $dN_p$ a function $T_p(S)\rightarrow T_{N(p)}(S)$?

Comment: By "differential," do Carmo is referring to the "differential of a map between surfaces," which he defines in Section 2-4.  See the Proposition 2 (in Section 2-4) and the discussion preceding it, which should (mostly) address both of your questions.

Comment: In general, if $\varphi \colon M \to N$ is a differentiable map from an $m$-dim manifold $M$ to an $n$-dim manifold $N$, one can speak of the **differential** (or **pushforward**) of $\varphi$ at $p \in M$, which is a linear $d\varphi_p \colon T_pM \to T_{\varphi(p)}N$. Two special cases: (a) If $M = \mathbb{R}^m$ and $N = \mathbb{R}^n$, one views $T_pM = \mathbb{R}^m$ and $T_{\varphi(p)}N = \mathbb{R}^n$, and $d\varphi_p \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the "total derivative." (b) If $M = S_1$ and $N = S_2$ are surfaces (i.e. 2-dim manifolds), this is do Carmo's notion in Section 2-4.